# Cast in Swift does not work for a generic UIViewController subclass

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller

I have a `ToastViewController` subclass of `UIViewController` with a generic `ToastContentView` being itself a subclass of `UIView`.

```
class ToastViewController<ContentViewType: ToastContentView>: UIViewController {
}

class ToastContentView: UIView {
}
```

I'm using custom view controller transitioning, and I need to cast my presenting view controller to `ToastViewController` from the `UIViewControllerContextTransitioning` instance.

```
if let toastVC = context.viewController(forKey: .to) as? ToastViewController<ToastContentView> {
  Log.debug("OK")
} else {
  Log.debug("NOT OK")
}
```

I have some concrete subclasses like `AlertViewController` defined like:

```
final class AlertViewController: ToastViewController<AlertToastView> {
}

final class AlertToastView: ToastContentView {
}
```

But the previous cast check always fails (whereas I'm sure the view controller is an instance of `AlertViewController`).

How can I make it work?
I obviously don't want to cast the presenting view controller to the concrete subclasses...

Thanks

Comment: Change the "Not OK" message to: `Log.debug("Not OK: \(context.viewController(forKey: .to)))`. What do you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, `AlertViewController` is a `ToastViewController<AlertToastView>`, not a `ToastViewController<ToastContentView>`, so you cannot cast.

A simple way to do this is to introduce a protocol with all the things you need from `ToastViewController`.

```
@MainActor
protocol AnyToastViewController: UIViewController {
    // declare properties/methods you need from ToastViewController here
}
```

If you need something of the generic `ContentViewType` type, add an associated type requirement to the protocol:

```
associatedtype Content: ToastContentView
var contentView: Content { get }
```

`ToastViewController`  would conform to it:

```
class ToastViewController<ContentViewType: ToastContentView>: UIViewController, AnyToastViewController {
```

Then you can cast to `any AnyToastViewController` instead.

```
if let toastVC = context.viewController(forKey: .to) as? ToastViewController<ToastContentView> {
    let content = toastVC.contentView
    // and so on...
} else {
    Log.debug("NOT OK")
}
```

Note that you can only *get* properties of the generic `ContentViewType` type, or call methods that return `ContentViewType`. Setting properties of type `ContentViewType`, or calling methods that take `ContentViewType` as a parameter is not type safe.